# Copying current command line to clipboard

Tags: zsh, clipboard

In `bash` with `set -o vi`, I use

```
bind '"\C-]":"\C-[A\C-u cb <<"EOF"\n\C-y\nEOF\n"'
```

to make `^]` in insert mode `cat` the current line to my clipboard wrapper (`cb`).

How do I emulate this in `zsh` (with `set -o vi`) ?

Answer (score 0):

These work for me:

```
copy-to-xclip() {
    zle kill-buffer
    print -rn -- $CUTBUFFER | cb
}; zle -N copy-to-xclip
bindkey -M viins "^]" copy-to-xclip

paste-xclip() {
    killring=("$CUTBUFFER" "${(@)killring[1,-2]}")
    CUTBUFFER=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)
    zle yank
}; zle -N paste-xclip
bindkey -M vicmd "p" paste-xclip
```